# Gnuplot: change power ten prefixes

Tags: gnuplot

I have some plots where I have a logarithmic axis ranging from 10^-6 to 10^6. For this, I use the format

```
set format y '%0.0s\,%c'
```

which gives the nice power of ten prefixes like micro (u), milli (m), kilo (k) and so on. However, I don't like the 'u' for micro, but I would like to use a 'mu' instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Not directly possible at the moment (as of gnuplot5.0pl4).

You will have to set your ticslabels manually.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. I will try to program a patch for that. Let's see whether the gnuplot community will accept it :-)